# Length of string output differs between dev and prod

Tags: php, adodb

Go easy on me since I'm new to PHP ;)

My development stack is Windows 7 with XAMP, My live server is a turnkey LAMP stack.

I'm using ADODB to connect to MSSQL and append all the results into a string with the code below:

```
    $sql = "SELECT Field1 FROM tb_Table";

        $rs = $db->Execute($sql); 

         if (!$rs) {
            print $db->ErrorMsg(); 
        } else {

            $arr = $rs->GetRows();
            $rows = '';
            //Loop through parent array (rows)
                for ($i=0;$i<=(count($arr)-1);$i++) {
                    $rows .= " ".$arr[$i][0]." ";
                }
print strlen($rows)
```

The string length on my local machine is 195,057 on the Server it is 136,858

I have checked that the same number of rows has been returned from the database, but I don't understand why the length of the string should differ between environments.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated

Comment: SUre it's the very same data? (not just the same number of rows)

Comment: You checked for same number of rows but are you sure each row is the same?

Comment: Yes, as near as can be, the sql is identical and whilst the amount of data can grow (but only by a few reocrds a day), the prod string is always much shorter than the dev string. I've got both instances open in front of me and running them at once they both return differing results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sussed it. The issue wasn't the code it was the provider, the provider on the Linux box only returns a maximum length of 255 from the field.

The windows provider returns the full length of the field.

Thanks everyone for looking :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with the ADODB extension, but you could try changing your `for` loop to this:

```
foreach($arr as $row) {
    $rows .= " ".$row[0]." ";
}
```

This will work around the possibility that the keys assigned to the array aren't contiguous.

If that doesn't help, try calculating the string length with `mb_strlen()` instead, as it will work with encodings that contain multiple byte characters:

```
print mb_strlen($rows);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately I get the same results.